# Use ngModel with plain ngController instead of directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

In my application I would like to preserve the option of using plain controllers for certain sections of code - as opposed to creating directives for one-off things that will never be re-used.

In these cases I often want to publish some data from the controller to be used in the contained section.  Now, I am aware that I could simply bind items in the controller's scope, however I'd like to specify the "model" location explicitly just to make the code more maintainable and easier to read.  What I'd like to use is ng-model as it would be used on a custom directive, but just along side my plain controller:

```
<div ng-controller="AppController" ng-model='fooModel'>
  {{fooModel}}
</div>
```

However I can see no way to get a reference to the generated ngModelController without using a directive and the 'require' injection.

I am aware that I could make my own attribute fairly easily by injecting the $attr into my controller and do something like:

```
<div ng-controller="AppController" my-model='fooModel'>
  {{fooModel}}
</div>
```

In which case I just manually take or parse the myModel value and stick my model into the $scope under that name.  However that feels wrong in this case - I really only need one "model" for a controller and I'd prefer not to have to add this boilerplate to every controller when ngModel exists.  (It's the principle of the thing!)

My questions are:

1) Is there some way to use ngModel along with a *plain* controller to get the effect above?

2) I have been trying to figure out where ngModelControllers are stored so that I could look at the situation in the debugger but have not been able to find them. When using an ngModel directive should I see these in the scope or parent scope?  (Where do they live?!?)

UPDATE: As suggested in answers below $element.controller() can be used to fetch the controller.  This works (http://plnkr.co/edit/bZzdLpacmAyKy239tNAO?p=preview) However it's a bit unsatisfying as it requires using $evalAsync.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 2) I have been trying to figure out where ngModelControllers are stored so that I could look at the situation in the debugger but have not been able to find them. When using an ngModel directive should I see these in the scope or parent scope? (Where do they live?!?)

The answer depends slightly on where you want to access the controller from.

**From outside the element with `ng-model`**

It requires "name" attributes on both the element with the `ng-model` attribute, and a parent form (or `ngForm`). So say you have the form with name `myForm` and the element with `ng-model` attribute with name `myInput`, then you can access the `ngModelController` for `myFoo` from the parent scope as `myForm.myInput`. For example, for debugging purposes:

```
<p>myFoo: {{myForm.myInput.$modelValue}}<p>
<form name="myForm">
  <div ng-controller="InnerController" name="myInput" ng-model="model.foo"></div>
</form>
```

as can be seen at http://plnkr.co/edit/IVTtvIXlBWXGytOEHYbn?p=preview

**From inside the element with `ng-model`**

Similar to the [answer from @pixelbits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25346540/1319998), using `$evalAsync` is needed due to the order of controller creation, but you can alternatively use angular.element.controller function to retrieve it:

```
app.controller('InnerController', function($scope, $element) {
  $scope.$evalAsync(function() {
    $scope.myModelController = $element.controller('ngModel');
  });
});
```

Used, inside the controller to view it, for debugging purposes, as:

```
<div ng-controller="InnerController" ng-model="model.foo">
  <p>myFoo: {{myModelController.$modelValue}}<p>
</div>
```

As can be seen at http://plnkr.co/edit/C7ykMHmd8Be1N1Gl1Auc?p=preview .

---

> 1) Is there some way to use ngModel along with a plain controller to get the effect above?

Once you have the `ngModelController` inside the directive, you can change its value just as you would were you using a custom directive accessing the `ngModelController`, using the `$setViewValue` function:

```
myModelController.$setViewValue('my-new-model-value');
```

You can do this, for example, in response to a user action that triggers an `ngChange` handler.

```
app.controller('InnerController', function($scope, $element) {
  $scope.$evalAsync(function() {
    $scope.myModelController = $element.controller('ngModel');
  });

  $scope.$watch('myModelController.$modelValue', function(externalModel) {
    $scope.localModel = externalModel;
  });

  $scope.changed = function() {
    $scope.myModelController.$setViewValue($scope.localModel);
  };
});
```

Note the extra watcher on `$modelValue` to get the initial value of the model, as well as to react to any later changes.

It can be used with a template like:

```
{{model.foo}}
<div ng-controller="InnerController" ng-model="model.foo">
  <p><input type="text" ng-model="localModel" ng-change="changed()"></p>
</div>
```

Note that this uses `ngChange` rather than a watcher on `localModel`. This is deliberate so that `$setViewValue` is only called when the user has interacted with the element, and not in response to changes to the model from the parent scope.

This can be seen at http://plnkr.co/edit/uknixs6RhXtrqK4ZWLuC?p=preview

---

Edit: If you would like to avoid `$evalAsync`, you can use a watcher instead.

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
  return $element.controller('ngModel');
}, function(ngModelController) {
  $scope.myModelController = ngModelController;
});
```

as seen at http://plnkr.co/edit/gJonpzLoVsgc8zB6tsZ1?p=preview

---

As a side-note, so far I seem to have avoided nesting plain controllers like this. I think if a certain part of the template's role is to control a variable by `ngModel`, it is a prime candidate for writing a small directive, often with an isolated scope to ensure there are no unexpected effects due to scope inheritance, that has a clear API, and uses `require` to access the `ngModelController`. Yes, it might not be reused, but it does help enforce a separation of responsibilities between parts of the code.

Comment: Thank you! This plunker uses your technique but matches my original question: http://plnkr.co/edit/bZzdLpacmAyKy239tNAO?p=preview   Is there some alternative to the mysterious evalAsync? Can I use a $watch for the controller?

Comment: @PatNiemeyer You can. I've added a part that shows how.

Answer (score 2):

When you declare directives on an element:

```
<div ng-controller="AppController" ng-model='fooModel'>
  {{fooModel}}
</div>
```

You can retrieve the controller instance for any directive by calling jQlite/jQuery [$element.data(nameOfController)](http://api.jquery.com/data/), where nameOfController is the normalized name of the directive with a `$` prefix, and a `Controller` suffix.

For example, to retrieve the controller instance for the `ngModel` directive you can do:

```
var ngModelController = $element.data('$ngModelController');
```

This works as long as the `ngModel` directive has already been registered.

Unfortunately, `ngController` executes with the same priority as `ngModel`, and for reasons that are implementation specific, `ngModel` is not registered by the time that the `ngController` function executes.  For this reason, the following does not work:

```
app.controller('ctrl', function ($scope, $element) {
     var ngModelController = $element.data('$ngModelController');

     // this alerts undefined because ngModel has not been registered yet
     alert(ngModelController);
});
```

To fix this, you can wrap the code within [$scope.$evalAsync](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$evalAsync), which guarantees that the directives have been registered before the callback function is executed:

```
app.controller('ctrl', function ($scope, $element) {
     $scope.$evalAsync(function() {
        var ngModelController = $element.data('$ngModelController');
        alert(ngModelController);
     });
});
```

[Demo JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xg9ktv20/)

Comment: Thanks - this was the answer.  But is there any alternative to the mysterious $evalAsync?  Perhaps something that can be $watched?